# A simple way of using Arithmetic operators such as a = a + 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
mylist[2][1][3] = mylist[2][1][3] + 1
```

`mylist` is a list that contains lists of lists of numbers, and I want to add 1 to a specific number within an inner list.

To change the number, however, I need to type `mylist[2][1][3]` multiple times, once on each side of the `=`

Is there a better way to write this code, since it makes it less readable once you have different variable names?

Current code:

```
myDataID7[myDataID5[3][6]][myDataID3][7][4][1]] = myDataID7[myDataID5[3][6]][myDataID3][7][4][1]] + 1
```

Ideal code:

```
something = myDataID7[myDataID5[3][6]][myDataID3][7][4][1]]
something = something + 1
```

Comment: use `+=` ex: `a += 1` instead `a = a+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple feature in Python which allows you to avoid repeating the same thing twice.

Instead of using `=`, you can use `+=`

Example usage:

`mylist[2][1][3] = mylist[2][1][3] + 1`, can be changed into

`mylist[2][1][3] += 1`

Comment: It's generally not worth a self-answered question for trivial functionality covered in tutorials. How would someone with a similar problem find, or even know to look for, this?

Comment: When creating my code, it didn't seem obvious to me to use `+=`, despite having many years of experience of coding. When trying to find a solution on Stack Overflow, I couldn't find any answers which included an item in a list being written twice, simply to add 1 to it. I only realised while writing the question, which is why I decided to share it instead of delete the question for anyone else who ran into the same situation. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Same question, though. What would you search for to find this? The title is so specific to what turns out not to be your actual code. How would you even know there was something to look for?

Comment: I was searching for something to do with not needing to write the list on both sides of the `=`. If you can think of a better title which would make it easier to find for these searches, please let me know @jonrsharpe

Comment: This is one of the first things you learn; maybe you could change the title to "Increase variable in Python" or something, but I really think, that this is not worth a SO post

Comment: You can find all of them and more in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters ..  you can find most of them also as "long" version in https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html - just dont make a question per operator, this would be just silly.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** (read more : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

What you can do is use `a += b` which is the same as `a = a + b`. Same goes for other basic operations `/=`, `-=`, `*=`

*Demo*:

**Addition**

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a += 1
>>> print(a)
3
```

**Subtraction**

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a -= 1
>>> print(a)
1
```

**Division**

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a /= 1
>>> print(a)
2
```

**multiplication**

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a *= 1
>>> print(a)
2
```